# AWS Batch job fails with Status Task failed to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

Any ideas what can trigger this status?

[image]

Comment: The compute env is fargate or ec2?

Comment: The compute env is EC2

Comment: Can you go to ECS console, go to cluster, find your task that failed. Usually there is more info there.

Comment: Thank you! I found the problem there

Comment: No problem. What was the issue?

Comment: Missing docker image.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Marcin in the comments, more information can be found in:

ECS console -> Cluster associated with the Batch Job -> Tasks